# In form submit, only radio buttons not passing value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I'm having some problems submitting values from radio buttons. After I press the submit button all values are passed to the corresponding properties, but only the  with type radio is not submitting any value. I'm using ASP .NET Core 2.2 and writing in C#. The radio buttons are stars which I took from this link: https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh I have used them before and they worked.
This is my View:

```
@model CreateReviewViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Review";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h4>Bar Review</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-controller="Bars" asp-action="Review" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <input asp-for="UserId" value="@User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)" hidden />

            <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset class="rating__stars">
                        <input type="radio" id="star5" asp-for="Rate" name="rating__stars5" value="5" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star4half" asp-for="Rate" name="rating__stars" value="4.5" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star4" asp-for="Rate" name="rating__stars" value="4" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star3half" asp-for="Rate" name="rating__stars" value="3.5" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star3" asp-for="Rate" name="rating__stars" value="3" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star2half" asp-for="Rate" name="rating__stars" value="2.5" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star2" asp-for="Rate" name="rating__stars" value="2" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star1half" asp-for="Rate" name="rating__stars" value="1.5" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star1" asp-for="Rate" name="rating__stars" value="1" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="starhalf" asp-for="Rate" name="rating__stars" value="0.5" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
                    </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <br />
                <br />
                <label asp-for="Comment" class="control-label">Message </label>
                <textarea asp-for="Comment" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Comment" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

And this is my action:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Member")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Review(CreateReviewViewModel reviewViewModel)
    {
        var barReview = reviewViewModel.ToBarDTO();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _barManager.CreateBarReviewAsync(barReview);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

After submitting only the form, each property of the CreateViewModel is completed except the Rate property.
This is the viewModel:

```
public class CreateReviewViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The "name" attribute in a HTML form element determines the parameter name which is sent to the server containing the field's data. This must match the name in your model object for the ASP.NET model binder to know which property of your model to attach the value to. In your HTML code you've manually specified `rating__stars` as the name for your radio buttons (apart from one of them which you've randomly named `name="rating__stars5` instead). This does not match the `Rate` property in your model. ASP.NET cannot magically know that you intended these two strings to represent the same thing.

Comment: have you tried reading it as a string and converting it to its decimal value?

Comment: [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) has your answer. FYI, why do you have decimal ratings? It would seem like you would want int ratings for options with a decimal overall

Comment: Thank you ADyson, I thought it was supposed to be the same name as the class.